# Is there a way to format a json byte array and write it to a file?

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have a byte array that I made, and I am writing it to a json file. This works, but I want to have a formatted JSON file instead of a massive wall of text.

I have tried decoding the byte array with utf-8, but instead I get `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte`. My plan was to then take this string and use json.dumps() to format it.

Trying json.dumps() without any other formatting gives this: `TypeError: Object of type bytearray is not JSON serializable`

```
content = bytearray()
content_idx = 0

try:
  with open(arguments.input_file, 'rb') as input_file:
    while (byte:=input_file.read(1)):
      content += bytes([ord(byte) ^ xor_key[content_idx % (len(xor_key))]])
      content_idx += 1
except (IOError, OSError) as exception:
  print('Error: could not read input file')
  exit()

try:
  with open(arguments.output_file, 'wb') as output_file:
    output_file.write(json.dumps(content.decode('utf-8'), indent=4))
except (IOError, OSError) as exception:
  print('Error: could not create output file')
  exit()
```

Comment: Json is a poor format for storing arbitrary byte arrays since it's not a native json data type.  If you must use json, you could use [Base64 encoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html) to turn it into a string.

Comment: @craigb i see.. I just have a .gdata file that I need to convert into json. Would Base64 encoding still be readable?

Comment: What do you consider "readable" for a bunch of bytes?

Comment: `bytearray` isn't json serializable. I'm still stuck on that first "This works".

Comment: @MarkTolonen I meant like after the json file is outputted

Comment: @tdelaney Replacing "output_file.write(json.dumps(...))" with "output_file.write(content)" works for some reason

Comment: And I mean what do you want it to look like? My answer is readable, and reversible, so you can restore the original data.

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you are trying to pass then bytes, and `json.dumps()` is trying to serialize them somehow, but can't, which is written in the error output.

To save the file in JSON you need to translate the byte stream into a Python dictionary, which will already accept JSON perfectly and without problems.

It would help if you could show what the input data looks like and what you want to save to JSON

Python has an off-the-shelf Base64 library that can translate an array of bytes into a string, and [here's an example usage article](https://stackabuse.com/encoding-and-decoding-base64-strings-in-python/). But the problem may arise later when parsing that string into the dictionary, so maybe I'd advise you to google what libraries are probably ready for such parsing, but otherwise you can use regular expressions

Comment: That error means that `content.decode('utf-8')` before it even gets to `json.dumps`.  How would one convert a byte stream into a python dictionary? That sounds like magic.

Comment: to do this you need to translate the byte stream into text and parse it with ready serializers or regular expressions

Comment: My input data is a really weird .gdata file, but if you want it I can give it to you

Answer (score 0):

The JSON encoder and decoder can be extended to support other types.  Here's one way to support byte strings by converting them to a BASE64 `str` and serializing it as a `dict` with special key.  The key is used to flag the decoder to convert the JSON object with that key back to a byte string.

```py
import json
import base64

class B64Encoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    '''Recognize a bytes object and return a dictionary with
    a special key to indicate its value is a BASE64 string.
    '''
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, bytes):
            return {'__B64__': base64.b64encode(obj).decode('ascii')}
        return super().default(obj)

def B64Decoder(obj):
    '''Recognize a dictionary with the special BASE64 key
    and return its BASE64-decoded value.
    '''
    if '__B64__' in obj:
        return base64.b64decode(obj['__B64__'])
    return obj

d = {'key1': bytes.fromhex('0102030405'), 'key2': b'\xaa\x55\x00\xff'}
print(f'Python IN: {d}')
print('\nJSON:')
s = json.dumps(d, indent=2, cls=B64Encoder)
print(s)
d2 = json.loads(s, object_hook=B64Decoder)
print(f'\nPython OUT: {d}')
```

Output:

```json
Python IN: {'key1': b'\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05', 'key2': b'\xaaU\x00\xff'}

JSON:
{
  "key1": {
    "__B64__": "AQIDBAU="
  },
  "key2": {
    "__B64__": "qlUA/w=="
  }
}

Python OUT: {'key1': b'\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05', 'key2': b'\xaaU\x00\xff'}
```